# Why does C# NuGet package WebDriverManager download the latest ChromeDriver instead of matching the installed Chrome version?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I use WebDriverManager to automatically download the latest ChromeDriver. But I have found out it download the latest ChromeDriver even when Chrome is not updated yet.

This is an issue, because my VM kicks off Selenium and Chrome automatically. Somehow Chrome doesn't update this way, so the ChromeDriver leads and Selenium gives me this error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 56537
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.129 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

I have configured WebDriverManager this way in my script:

```
IWebDriver driver;
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
SeleniumService selenium;
ChromeOptions Options = new();
Options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

using (driver = new ChromeDriver(Options))
{
    selenium = new(driver);
    try
    {
...
```

**Question:**
Can I somehow configure that WebDriverManager checks the installed Chrome version instead of downloading the latest ChromeDriver regardless of Chrome version?